# Do snap files get larger?

Tags: snap

I noticed with disc analyzer that my disk free space is gone down
from 974 GB to 971 GB over time on system updates and my snaps folder
went from 1 GB to 3 GB.

Do system snaps get larger as system updates get newer?

Answer (score 8):

Old versions of snaps are retained by the system but you can remove them and control what goes on behind the scenes.

The default number of versions retained is 3 but there is a snap option to use in terminal to reduce that to 2:

```
sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2
```

and you can write a script to remove old snap revisions.

[This reference](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-remove-old-snap-versions-to-free.html) shows you how.

Comment: "The default number of versions retained is 3" — just as a clarification: here 3 means the one being used currently and two previous older versions, right? So `refresh.retain=2` would mean: current, and only one previous instance, right?

Comment: The linked reference answers that with "to set the maximum number of a snap's revisions stored by the system after the next refresh".

Comment: I can't figure it out even from that whole sentence... (Update: if I _had to_ guess, I would say "revisions" mean only old versions, and the current one does not count in "revisions"...)

Comment: @Levente Revisions include the latest and previous snap. You should be able to check by comparing the results of ```snap list``` and ```snap list --all``` and looking at the 'Rev' column. ```snap list```  will show you the latest/currently in use version, or 'revision', or each of your snaps. ```snap list --all``` shows the latest and previous revisions. If you use the ```refresh.retain=2``` option, you should have 2 of each snap: the latest revision, and one previous revision.

Comment: @wizardpurple thank you! Now that I see only two of everything, I wanted to see whether my retain value is set to `2` by default. But when I try `sudo snap get system refresh.retain` I get `error: snap "core" has no "refresh.retain" configuration option`. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2, snap/snapd is `2.50.1`.

Comment: `sudo snap get system refresh` returns literally: `Key  Value`

Comment: @Levente by default, "refresh.retain=3 on Ubuntu Core systems and refresh.retain=2 on classic Ubuntu systems, such as those running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)" ([src](https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date)). And it appears that by default, "Options are not visible until after they are set. The snap get command can then be used to check their state" ([system options doc](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/system-options/87)) which seems very odd that they wouldn't return a default value.